# Transition not being captured by subtree & attribute breakpoints Chrome developer tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a webpage on which if a tab key is pressed when in the last textbox a side pane from the right slides(like a side menu).

In chrome development tools I can see it is an `aside` tag with classes `control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark` but setting DOM break points(subtree & attribute) on the aside tag is not capturing anything.

On looking into DOM it seems like it is not being manipulated at all(which I expected sliding in should be doing) as I do not see the color blink on HTML tags that chrome developer tool shows for the affected elements.

I was expecting the javascript to be handling the sliding in of the aside tag but how could it be determined in this scenario? Could this be due to CSS only animation or something if yes than how to debug that?

I also tried to record in the `animation tab` of developer tools but it also stays blank.

This is happening on a privileged section of the site so I m sorry for not being able to put code sample or URL.

PS: The template is some modified version of http://www.ampleadmin.wrappixel.com/ampleadmin-html/ampleadmin-rtl/index.html(the navigation panel on right) but it is getting recorded in dev tool animation panel while mine doesnt.

Comment: Sounds like a trivial CSS `transition`.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes It looks like.The `.control-sidebar` has `transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out` but disabling it doesnt changes anything & Im also not able to record anything in the Animation tab of dev tools.

Comment: Transitions can't be recorded AFAIK. It's possible the site uses the [animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) from js, which may also be missing from the recording (that's a guess).

Comment: What if we need to determine which property is being animated on an element on a certain action like hover or click?

Comment: I would try to record what happens in devtools `performance` panel. If the changes are made in js, you'll be able to quickly find it using the flamechart.

Comment: what if it animation only without JS? If I need to change something in transition how to reach the particular CSS property responsible?

Comment: Well, my point is that you need to find how the animation is performed instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause. There are anchor tags inside the panel which get focused on when the tab is pressed from last textbox. There was no animation,CSS or JS involved.

Anchor(A) tags are focus able by default and the panel dont slide in when they are removed.